# how to share VPN connection to instances in private subnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, vpn

I created 2 instances:

- **VM-A** in a public subnet
- **VM-B** in a private subnet

I followed this guide and could make it work. **VM-B** can access internet (via **VM-A**): https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/vpc-nat-instance/

On **VM-A** I've setup OpenVPN and it can connect to our VPN server in our office.

Now I would like **VM-B** to be able to use the VPN connection of **VM-A** to access machines in our office but I can't find a way how to do it.

I think I know why it is not working, because in the route table of **VM-B** I have:

```
Destination    Target
10.0.0.0/16    local
0.0.0.0/0      eni-xxxx
```

The network interface eni-xxxx belongs to **VM-A**. So the traffic is going there.

Instead I would like to add something like this but it seems not possible because "tun0" is not a valid resource ID:

```
Destination
10.100.7.2 (network in our office accessible via VPN)

Target
tun0 (the network interface created by OpenVpn)
```

Any advice on how to solve this issue?

Extra question:
Is it a good practice to add routes using the "route add" command or is it better to use the Web interface "Route Tables" in the VPC dashboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I was missing a rule in the firewall to masquerade the address.
On **VM-A**:

```
# the subnet of VM-B is 10.0.30.0/24
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -s 10.0.30.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```